# Redirect in Laravel middleware

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect, middleware

I am creating custom middleware that depending on members role, returns certain view.

If check is passed, returns view with some parameters, if not returns some other view, no parameters.

Returning view gets url in address bar unchanged, despite "redirect".
I say under quotation marks, since redirects don't work, returning view does.
If i try to use redirects it goes in infinite loop.

Here are my routes:

```
    Route::get('/welcome', 'MembersController@welcome')->name('welcome');//Accessible at all times
    Route::get('/index', "MembersController@index")->name('index')->middleware(['auth', 'IsAdmin']);
    Route::post('/store', "MembersController@store")->name('store')->middleware(['auth', 'IsAdmin']);
    Route::patch('/update/{id}', "MembersController@update")->name('update')->middleware(['auth', 'IsAdmin']);
    Route::delete('/delete/{id}', "MembersController@destroy")->name('destroy')->middleware(['auth', 'IsAdmin']);
    Route::get('/show/{id}', "MembersController@show")->name('show')->middleware(['auth', 'IsAdmin']);
```

Here is my middleware:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {   
            $path = "C:/xampp/htdocs/EIDReader/public/EIDReaderApi/";
            $imageName = "avatar.jpg";
    
            $data = new \stdClass();
            $data->output = "";
            $data->retval = "";
            $data->personData = null;
    
            exec("C:/xampp/htdocs/EIDReader/public/EIDReader.exe", $data->output, $data->retval);
    
            if($data && $data->output && !empty($data->output[8]) && isset($data->output[8])){
    
                $personData = json_decode(str_replace("'", "", $data->output[8]));
            
                $folderPath = $data->output[4];
        
                $index = strrpos($folderPath, "/");
                $personImageFolder = substr($folderPath, $index+1);
                $imageName = "avatar.jpg";
                $imagePath = $personImageFolder."/".$imageName;
                
                $member = Members::where([["docRegNo", "=", $personData->docRegNo], ["personalNumber", "=", $personData->personalNumber]])->first();
                
                if($member && $member->role_id && $member->role_id==1){
                    
                    $members = Members::paginate(5);
                    //return redirect()->route("index", [$members]);//This doesn't work. Goes in infinite loop.
                    return response()->view("pages.index", compact("members"));//This works, but url in address bar doesn't change.
    
                }
                else{
    
                    //return redirect()->route("welcome");//This doesn't work. Goes in infinite loop.
                    return response()->view("welcome");//This works, but url in address bar doesn't change.
                    
                }
                
            }
    
        }
```

Only route that isn't covered by middleware is welcome page.

I tried different syntaxes for both, only thing i didn't try is to change url in address bar programmatically if use display view.

**Data it's receiving, is used for authentication. So no default auth.**

Underlying question is, how to redirect to page, with parameters passed, and with it, url in address bar is changed that correspond to page url?

**EDIT1:**

Data is received from smart card. Received data is then compared with records in db. If found, it then looks if record has appropriate `role_id`.
If `role_id` is appropriate, then middleware check is passed, and everything is aces...

And again, problem isn't in logic, problem is, is that if i use `return redirect()->route("someRoute");` it gets stuck in infinite loop.
Returning view doesn't.
How to redirect? Without infinite loop(ofcourse)?

**EDIT2:**

Apparently there was mistake/error in my understanding what `$next($request)` does.
Let me explain for other who look at this:

`$next($request)` says: If condition is passed, proceed with request i.e. go to chosen route.

In my case, if user choses route `index`:

```
    //And condition turns 'true', allow user to proceed to 'index'.
        if($member && $member->role_id && $member->role_id==1){
            return $next($request);   
          }
          else{//If condition returns 'false', then redirect to route 'welcome', i.e. route that allows to be redirected to e.g. not protected with middleware.
                return redirect()->route("welcome");
         }
```

**EDIT3:**

Also in routes ditched `auth`. Not sure why that stayed there...
So now:

```
//->middleware(['auth', 'IsAdmin']);
->middleware('IsAdmin');
```

Answer (score 0):

From edit2 which what solved my issue:

**EDIT2:**

Apparently there was mistake/error in my understanding what `$next($request)` does.
Let me explain for other who look at this:

`$next($request)` says: If condition is passed, proceed with request i.e. go to chosen route.

In my case, if user choses route `index`:

```
    //And condition turns 'true', allow user to proceed to 'index'.
        if($member && $member->role_id && $member->role_id==1){
            return $next($request);   
          }
          else{//If condition returns 'false', then redirect to route 'welcome', i.e. route that allows to be redirected to e.g. not protected with middleware.
                return redirect()->route("welcome");
         }
```

**EDIT3:**

Also in routes ditched `auth`. Not sure why that stayed there...
So now:

```
//->middleware(['auth', 'IsAdmin']);
->middleware('IsAdmin');
```